# Intellij: Adding a Tomcat Plugin in Maven menu

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm totally new to Tomcat and Maven, and I want to ask how to add a tomcat plugin in Maven. I want that Maven menu in IntelliJ will have tomcat option inside:

[image]

I don't have this option now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to include the Maven Tomcat Plugin in your pom.xml.
See sample code below.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost.com:1234/mymanager</url>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

See this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html) for more usage of the maven tomcat plugin.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment: don't put password and username in your POM.xml.

In your `<HOME-DIR>/.m2/settings.xml`:

```xml
<server>
   <id>tomcat8</id>
   <username>adminScript</username>
   <password>secret</password>
</server>
```

In your POM.xml

```xml
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- for Tomcat 8 also -->
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>tomcat8</server>
                <url>http://localhost.com:1234/mymanager</url>
                <path>/doorman</path>
            </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to make a few differences in pom.xml file: 
 1. version number of tomcat is 2.2 (2.3-SNAPSHOT doesn't work).
 2. -tag inside -tag is not mandatory. I removed it.
 3. I had to enter tags of username and password of tomcat manager inside -tag.

This is my pom.xml file that gave a working servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaCourse</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>                 <!--required-->
            <username>admin</username>  <!--required-->
            <password>admin</password>  <!--required-->
        </configuration>                <!--required-->
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: you should be aware that your POM.xml may be transferred to other developers inside/outside your company. So it's not a good idea to place `username` and `password` in POM.xml. Put it in your own settings.xml and refer to it via `server`.  In **settings.xml**:    `<server> <id>tomcat8</id>  <username>adminScript</username>  <password>secret</password> </server>`    In **POM.xml**: `<configuration><server>tomcat8</server><url>http://${tomcatServer}/manager/text</url>
<path>/doorman</path></configuration>`

Comment: the element `<url>` contains the URL to _**your**_ tomcat deployment service.